# C, exit and pcntl_wait functions produce multiples of 256, why?

Tags: php, c, exit, ubuntu-14.04, exit-code

I was writing a test to see if I could reliably determine the integer value of an exit code 
with `wait`.

### Questions

**1.** Why is the exit code multiplied by 256?
 **2.** Is `exit()`, `wait()`, the OS, or something else doing the multiplication?

The code to reproduce the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

// implementation is correct but irrelevant to the question
int compareInt(const void* a, const void* b); 

int main(void) {
    pid_t pids[6];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        pids[i] = pid;
        if (pid == 0) {
            exit(i);
        }
    }

    int codes[6];
    do {
        i--;
        wait(&codes[i]);
    } while (i > 0);

    const size_t num_elem = 6;
    qsort(codes, num_elem, sizeof(int), compareInt);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", codes[i]);
    }
    printf("%d\n", codes[5]);
    return 0;
}
```

**Outputs:** `0, 256, 512, 768, 1024, 1280`

As it turns out I should be using `wifexited(), wifstopped(), wifsignaled(), wexitstatus(), wtermsig(), or wstopsig()` to determine the exit status.

In addition the same behaviour is reproducible in PHP (where I first encountered it)

```
$pids = [];
foreach (range(0, 5) as $i) {
    $pids[] = $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if ($pid === 0) {
        exit($i);
    }
}

$exit_codes = [];
do {
    pcntl_wait($exit_codes[]);
    array_pop($pids);
} while (count($pids) > 0);

sort($exit_codes);
echo implode(', ', $exit_codes) . "\n";
```

**Outputs:** `0, 256, 512, 768, 1024, 1280`

If it makes a difference I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and `man wait` says I have `WAIT(2)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reasons you're seeing those results is because the returned value from `wait()` is encoded and contains information such as how and why the process was stopped as well as the actual exit status; this is why convenience macros are supplied to inspect certain parts of the return value.

A definition of `WEXITSTATUS(status)` can be found in `sys/wait.h` and may look like this:

```
#define WEXITSTATUS(status) (((status) & 0xff00) >> 8)
```

Or this:

```
#define WEXITSTATUS(status) (((status) >> 8) & 0x000000ff)
```

So you're seeing the multiplication because:

```
exit(1) -> 0x0100 (256)
exit(2) -> 0x0200 (512)
```

In PHP you would use [`pcntl_wexitstatus()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-wexitstatus.php) to accomplish the same thing; if the process was killed due to a signal there would be no exit status and you would need to use [`pcntl_wtermsig()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-wtermsig.php) to determine the signal that was used to kill it.

Comment: Hi Jack, I can't immediately grok your answer (though it probably is correct). I will have a closer look at it in the morning, it would help if you linked the resource to where you found the macro definition.

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for the great answer. This is totally demystified for me now.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `wait()` encodes several pieces of information. There are macros defined to pick apart the results and get just the nit you need. e.g. `WEXITSTATUS(result_of_wait)`.

Comment: Basically info on how the process ended - normal or not. read the man page for a full list.